# New Vanity: Sink Won't Drain Completely

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, drain-waste-vent

My wife and I just replaced the vanity in our bathroom. To fit the new sink, we had to cut some new PVC. Here's a picture.

[image: a]

All the plumbing works, without leaks, except that it will not drain completely out of the sink. After the sink stops draining, there is still about 1/2 inch of water standing in the sink.

All of the pipes that look horizontal are almost exactly horizontal. Did we not include enough of a downward slope? If so, how would we do that?

Comment: Where does the drain go inside the wall?  E.g. how far from the stack is it, and does it go uphill at any point?  Also, do you have an adjustable stopper in the sink, and if so, does the problem still happen if you remove it?

Comment: The old drain went into the wall and I don't know where it goes -- we just used what was there and was working. No, there is not an adjustable stopper. It's just a straight drain.

Comment: Is this new vanity shorter than the old one?  Or is it deaper than the old one?

Comment: It is slightly deeper than the old one, about 2-3 inches. It's also taller. The top of the P-trap was level with the pipe in the wall.

Comment: What's with the large amount of plumbers putty, is there a junction there being held with putty?

Comment: The sink drain had some drips where that threaded area connected to the non-threaded area. That wasn't anything we put together but I threw some putty on it to stop the drip.

Comment: When you took apart the old trap did a lot of water come out, or only a small amount?  Typically you should only see the amount of water the lower U bend of the trap can hold, If you find more comes out it's likely the drain goes up to meet the main drain.

Comment: There should be a compression fitting that screws onto the threaded pipe to secure the non-threaded pipe.  It should be similar to the one below that where the pipe connects to the top of the trap.

Comment: Only the amount of water that should have been in the P-trap came out.

Comment: Does the sink drain slowly, or does it drain normally (just not all the way)?  I would have to guess your looking at a clog.  If the drain went up before meeting the main drain there could be a problem, but since the normal amount of water drained out when you disconnected it I would doubt this is the case (also I couldn't see how it would pass inspection if it did).  Try some drain cleaner, or plunging. If that does not help look for a nearby clean-out or disconnect the trap and try snaking it out.

Comment: Would you be able to post a picture of the water sitting in the sink and the drain at the bottom?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Comment: The way the pipes are shown in the photo, it is an s-trap, not allowed by code. Even if there is a vent in the wall, there is an s-trap before the vent.

Answer (score 12):

This might not be the answer, but for reference here is a problem that can occur if the plumbing is not installed properly.

If you look at Fig. 3, this is what a proper drain looks like.  You'll notice the orange line represents the water level in the system, the water levels out in the trap preventing sewer gases from entering the sink drain.

In Fig. 1, you can see what will happen if the drain line has to go up before meeting the main drain line.  Again the orange line represents the water level in the system, and as you can see the water level is much higher in the drain.

Fig. 2 shows what could happen if the sink was installed lower than the rise in the drain line. The water would never fully drain from the sink, since it would require extra pressure in the system to push the water *up* the drain.

[image]

I wouldn't guess this is the issue in this case; since as you can see, if you opened the trap in this case you would have more water drain than what is typically in the trap.

In a perfect world Fig.1 and 2 would never pass inspection, but as we all know not all plumbing is properly installed and/or inspected. So this could possibly be the case in this situation (given the plumbing was installed by an *amateur* plumber), but it is doubtful. It would be more likely caused by a clog in the line.

Comment: Wow, this is a really detailed answer. Thank you for taking the time to write it out and draw those diagrams. My setup is like figure 3, so theoretically, it should work.

Comment: @michaelkoss: I figured from your comments that the plumbing was probably correct, that's why I suspect the problem is a clog.  Also for future reference, problems like this is why I never glue trap assemblies. I usually use compression fittings and threaded connectors, so the whole thing can be disassembled if there is a problem (or a ring or something falls down the drain).

Comment: @michaelkoss: Also, please get a proper fitting so you can remove that plumbers putty. That's a "*works for now*" solution, not a proper installation technique ;)

Comment: I assume Home Depot or Lowe's would have something to thread on there? How would I add it post-glue? I'm not opposed to cutting this out and doing it again if I need to. I'd rather it be right.

Comment: +1 for the pics @Tester.  I was thinking the same thing, hence my original comment.  If it was a clog, I'd expect it to always be slow.  The only thing left I can think of is an air bubble in the drain, hence my question about the adjustable stopper.

Comment: @michaelkoss: you should be able to add the new compression fitting by disconnecting the threaded connector in the middle of the trap assembly, then unscrewing the threaded connector that connects to the metal pipe. the lower U of the trap and the extension should be able to drop out, allowing you access to install the new fitting.

Comment: There are threaded connectors on there that will let the OP check/clean the trap. There is one between the chrome and trap and one just after the trap. Unthread those and check for hairballs. Run a snake down the main drain while you've got it apart anyway.

Comment: In figure 1, would the trap really be serving any purpose? And with regard to figure 3, I think most P-traps I've seen would not have the pipe go down before the horizontal run.

Comment: @supercat They're crappy inaccurate drawings done in MS paint used to explain a concept. Not to mention the post is 3 years old.  Give me a break.

Comment: @Tester101: I wasn't trying to belittle the drawings, but was wondering if they had been intended to be illustrative of more issues than what were described in the text.  For example, if there were a rise between the trap and the wall, might that create a pressure-lock condition between the two traps.

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue that doesn't meet the plumbing code. Before you drain down in the vertical there should be a vent. An air admittance valve will take care of that and probably your dining issue too

Comment: The vent pipe may be in the wall.